# Publishing with MSBuild with custom parameters

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I am publishing an application from Visual Studio 2012 (.NET 4.5).

I am using "File System" publishing method (I can not use "Web Deploy Package" also known as target:package).

As a result of publishing using "File System" method a folder is created containing entire application. Once again I do not want to (I can't) use webdeploy.

I am trying to parametarize files that are not related with web.config. For example I have a file that needs to be customised ~\app_config\tt.debug.config

I know how to customize such files using parameters.xml file - but it only works when I use "Web Deploy Package", how can I make it work using "File System" publishing method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to use parameters.xml in an easy way, but I was able to use a solution suggested [here](http://publicityson.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/visual-studio-xml-file-transformation.html).

In summary. It is a task that you plugin to build target, and it automatically transforms other configuration files. For example:

- tt.debug.config
- tt.release.config

will be transformed to tt.config